# Why is their Parameter of type View for an onClick Method

Tags: android

```
....
android:onClick = "activity1";
....

public void activity1(View view)
{
 .....
}
```

why is the parameter for this function of type View

Comment: Why wouldn't there be?

Comment: What type would you expect? If you think you'd get the type of view you attached it to well no... cast it to the type e.g Textview v = (TextView) view;

Comment: one reason is that you can reuse the same listener for multiple views, and you may want a way to understand which one was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

You can set an onClickListener on any View. That means that that listener does not know what kind of element you set the listener on.

Since all elements you can set an onClickListener on `extend View`, it gives you the view because it knows for sure that your element is a `View`.

You yourself can detect what element was clicked, and then you can cast it to the specific element if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Because View is the base class for all the widgets android has.

For example TextView extends View, ImageView extends view and so on.

And you can write View v = new TextView()

SO now you can use basic functionalities provided by View there, like getItemID etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same onClick on different Views. So in that case view would be use to identify which View was clicked.

For Example 
If there are 3 buttons with `android:onClick = "activity"`

You can do this

```
public void activity(View view)
{
    switch(view.getItemId()){

     case R.id.button1:
     break;
     case R.id.button2:
     break;
     case R.id.button3:
     break;

     }
}
```

Now you can use the same onClick on 3 different buttons.

Comment: This would also work if it was `activity(Button view)`, it does not really answer the question

Answer (score 0):

So that you can use same method for multiple different Views. 
Try the below code

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onActivityClick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onActivityClick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="onActivityClick" />
```

Now in your activity method `onActivityClick` will look like

```
public void onActivityClick(View view){
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.button1:
            //do something();
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            //do something();
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            //do something();
            break;
    }
}
```

So basically you can use same method for multiple widgets and save count of methods and extra code in your application.

Hope this helps.